# How to calculate the inverse of k mod p

Tags: c, gmp

I want to implement ELgamal algorithm using GMP, C language. I am unable to calculate
`m=(k^(-1)*num) mod p`

Comment: Post your code, specify where you are facing problems.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the function `mpz_invert()`. For more assistance, you'll need to provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

Modular inverses (privided that `p` is a prime) can be done with the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), which can be done recursively or iteratively.